# Create function in .profile to go to specific folder with zsh

Tags: bash, zsh

Prior to switching over from bash to zsh, I had a function in my `.profile` file to go directly to my Client folder. It looks like this;

```
function client {
  cd ~/Client/$1
}
alias cl="client"
```

This no longer works now that I've moved into using zsh and I have no idea why.  It does not recognize my alias. Am I doing something wrong or missed something extra?

Interestingly enough, other functions in my `.profile` do still work. Just not this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) [runs `~/.zprofile`, not `~/.profile`.](https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile)

---

To achieve the same in zsh, you won't need an `alias`, you could call the function by its name.

You could insert a function to `~/.zshrc` (or `~/.zprofile`) like this;

```
function client {
    cd /tmp/$1
}
```

And use it as expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how just some of your function in .profile are defined, but not all of them. While 0stone0 correctly says that Zsh usually does not read .profile (though it can be tricked into doing so), this would not explain the behaviour you see. Did you perhaps miss some error message?

I suggest that you trace a complete zsh invocation with

```
zsh -l -i -x
```

The `-l` forces zsh to believe that it is a login shell, the `-i` makes sure that it is run as interactive shell (though, if you start the command from the terminal prompt, this should be automatically the case), and the `-x` traces all the commands it executes on startup. If your claim is correct, that it loads `.profile`, but does not create all functions, you should see from this output at which point it fails.